# how to box formulas inside eqnarray*

Tags: math-mode

How to box formulas such as

```
\begin{eqnarray*}
&&P(X_{n+1} = i_{n+1}\mid
X_{0}=i_{0}, X_{1}=i_{1},\ldots,X_{n-1}=i_{n-1},X_{n}=i_{n}) \\
&&=P(X_{n+1}=i_{n+1}\mid X_{n}=i_{n}).
\end{eqnarray*}
```

I use `amsmath` package

```
\begin{eqnarray*}
p(x) &= 3x^6 + 14x^5y + 590x^4y^2 + 19x^3y^3\\
&- 12x^2y^4 - 12xy^5 + 2y^6 - a^3b^3
\end{eqnarray*}
```

Comment: `eqnarray` is 'outdated' -- rather use `align` or `alignat` (or the starred variants)

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196/eqnarray-vs-align

Answer (score 2):

Here are two versions: `empheq` and `tcolorbox`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}


%\begin{eqnarray*}
%&&P(X_{n+1} = i_{n+1}\mid
%X_{0}=i_{0}, X_{1}=i_{1},\ldots,X_{n-1}=i_{n-1},X_{n}=i_{n}) \\
%&&=P(X_{n+1}=i_{n+1}\mid X_{n}=i_{n}).
%\end{eqnarray*}

\begin{empheq}[box=\fbox]{align*}
   &P(X_{n+1} = i_{n+1}\mid X_{0}=i_{0}, X_{1}=i_{1},\dots,X_{n-1}=i_{n-1},X_{n}=i_{n}) \\
  ={}&P(X_{n+1}=i_{n+1}\mid X_{n}=i_{n})
\end{empheq}

\begin{tcolorbox}[ams align*,colback=white!40!yellow]
   &P(X_{n+1} = i_{n+1}\mid X_{0}=i_{0}, X_{1}=i_{1},\dots,X_{n-1}=i_{n-1},X_{n}=i_{n}) \\
  ={}&P(X_{n+1}=i_{n+1}\mid X_{n}=i_{n})
\end{tcolorbox}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `={}&` in both cases; and `\dots`, not `\ldots`

Comment: Thanks everybody. Do I understand correctly that I should use mathtools instead of  amsmath?   Replacing eqnarray* by align* did not help when I use amsmath

Comment: @user164118: `mathtools` makes some additions to `amsmath`

Comment: I found that \usepackage{amsmath}   suffices                                                        \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}




\begin{document}

\begin{eqnarray*}
\boxed{
       \begin{aligned}
\hbox{}&P(X_{n+1} = i_{n+1}\mid
X_{0}=i_{0}, X_{1}=i_{1},\ldots,X_{n-1}=i_{n-1},X_{n}=i_{n}) \\
\hbox{}&=P(X_{n+1}=i_{n+1}\mid X_{n}=i_{n}).
\end{aligned}
       }
\end{eqnarray*}



\end{document}

Comment: @user164118: That's another possibility, of course. But you still use the outdated `eqnarray` stuff.

Comment: @ Christian  Thanks again. I  am very happy with your suggestion to use align rather than eqnarray. Indeed this gives a much nicer result.